# plot polygon on picture

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to follow sample guide and have managed to create my own annotations for my own images. https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ground_truth_labeling_jobs/ground_truth_object_detection_tutorial/object_detection_tutorial.html#Create-the-instruction-template

This is the content of my `fids2bbs`

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'image1.jpg': [['Servers', '1368', '1385', '1035', '195'], ['Servers', '1170', '1381', '1040', '189']], 'image11.jpg': [['Servers', '974', '1373', '1058', '185'], ['Servers', '1172', '1380', '1048', '188']], 'image13.jpg': [['Servers', '889', '1350', '1072', '189'], ['Servers', '1087', '1361', '1054', '191']], 'image14.jpg': [['Servers', '840', '1323', '1081', '194'], ['Servers', '1051', '1338', '1055', '184']], 'image15.jpg': [['Servers', '803', '1308', '1084', '202'], ['Servers', '1011', '1311', '1081', '202']]})
```

the format of the coords are top, left, width , hight

Here is the code that I am using to plot

```
# Plot sample images.
def plot_bbs(ax, bbs, img):
    '''Add bounding boxes to images.'''
    ax.imshow(img)
    imh, imw, _ = img.shape
    for bb in bbs:
        xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = bb
        xmin *= imw
        xmax *= imw
        ymin *= imh
        ymax *= imh
        rec = plt.Rectangle((xmin, ymin), xmax-xmin, ymax-ymin, fill=None, lw=20, edgecolor='blue')
        ax.add_patch(rec)

plt.figure(facecolor='white', dpi=100, figsize=(4, 8))
plt.suptitle('Please draw a box\n around each {}\n like the examples below.\n Thank you!'.format(CLASS_NAME), fontsize=15)

for fid_id, (fid, bbs) in enumerate([list(fids2bbs.items())[idx] for idx in [0, 1]]):
    !aws s3 cp s3://sagemaker-eu-west-2-.../ground-truth-od-full-demo/test/{fid} .
    img = imageio.imread(fid)
    bbs = [[float(a) for a in annot[1:]] for annot in bbs]
    ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, fid_id+1)
    plot_bbs(ax, bbs, img)
    plt.axis('off')

plt.savefig('instructions.png', dpi=60)
with open('instructions.png', 'rb') as instructions:
    instructions_uri = base64.b64encode(instructions.read()).decode('utf-8').replace('\n', '')
```

The image I am using is 3840 × 2160

My code doesn't seem to plot correctly.